# Multi_match query always returns empty results

Tags: elasticsearch

As per the elasticsearch 5.1 documentation, I have built the following query to implement a basic search functionality on a subset of the piece of software I am building. For some reason, this query never returns any results even if all of the fields are present. All users are guaranteed to have all of these fields, but to be safe I tested it with each individual field and got the same result each time.

```
"query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                    "displayName",
                    "title",
                    "team",
                    "teamLeader"
                ],
                "query": "a",
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also attempted using other types like `best_fields`, `phrase_prefix`, etc. to no avail. I know the data is there because my filter query works just fine, but suddenly no data returns after I add this section. Is there anything I can do to better debug this situation?

Comment: My guts tell me that all those fields are analyzed and since `a` is a stop word it gets removed during the analysis process. Feel free to provide your mapping and a sample document that you think should get returned so we can validate my hypothesis.

Comment: Well even for full names etc I run into the same issue. For instance, if I had someone named 'Jeff' and I looked them up by name, it would not return anything still.

Comment: It'd be nice if there's a way to reproduce the problem, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark ;-)

Comment: Hey, you were absolutely right. Something was up with my mapping on the fields I was referencing. When I used a more common field, firstName, everything appeared as intended. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;-)